# How to interpret the coefficients of Tweedie GLM with log link?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, tweedie-distribution

I'm trying to model  cost data which have 0s. It seems that gamma is not an appropriate distribution and zero inflated gamma seems to be a bit of an overkill, but Tweedie seems to be appropriate with a high level of flexibility.

After running a GLM with Tweedie distribution with log link, do the exponentiated coefficients have the same interpretation as gamma? (i.e., multiplicative increase or decrease)?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. The link function determines the mean $E(Y|X) = \mu$ as a function of $X\beta$.

In the log-case you get:

$$ \log(\hat{\mu}) = X\beta  \rightarrow  \hat{\mu} = \prod_{i=1}^p e^{X_i \beta_i}, $$

where $p$ is the number of features. This implies you have the same interpretation as in log-Link using Gamma (or any other distribution).

The choice of distribution is a property of $Y$, this will lead to different likelihood, and therefore to different coefficients (even if the link function is identical).

Comment: Ben Bolker: Thank you for the response! If I'm using zero inflated gamma with identity link to get the linear difference as opposed to ratio, would that work in glmmTMB? (i.e., ziGamma(link="identity")?